# Test and Mock framework for Java and .NET

Tags: java, .net, tdd, mocking, testing

I'd like to know your thoughts about test/mocking frameworks that are widely used and have a good level of compatibility between Java and .NET. I mean, I want to learn those tools to use in a .NET project, but I still wanna be able to apply that knowledge in Java projects.

- I know there're many questions about test/mocking frameworks to those platforms especifically here in SO, but I've not found one question comparing those frameworks regarding its similarities in those two platforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The N/J-series of frameworks ([**NUnit**](http://nunit.org)/**[JUnit](http://www.junit.org)**, [**NMock**](http://www.nmock.org)/[**JMock**](http://www.jmock.org/), etc.) are typically parallel ports of each other or are based on the same starting principles. Those will definitely let you transfer at least some of your knowledge between them.

Comment: For the record, JMock2 is significantly different from JMock1 (from which NMock was cloned). It doesn't use strings for method names any more.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest that you take a look at [Moq](http://moq.me/) for mocking in .NET. It is conceptually very similar to Mockito on the Java side.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I see from my experience on the Java side of the fence.

**Unit testing frameworks**

As for unit testing in Java, pretty much everyone is using JUnit and with JUnit 4.0 using annotations I understand that it is more like NUnit now.

**Mocking frameworks**

We were using [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/) on our project for about half a year and we determined that it was eating up a lot of our time just to do simple tasks. Actually, we made a lot of jokes about how EasyMock is not easy.

After attending a lecture on mocking frameworks, I decided to go with [Mockito](http://www.mockito.org) and have never looked back. It allows partial mocking painlessly - something that EasyMock required a separate library for. Also, Mockito has much better error messaging. When you do something wrong, it will give you verbose errors on how you violated Mockito's contract.

Anyways, give both a spin and I think you will agree that Mockito is a clear winner.

Comment: +1 for Mockito. It's far better than EasyMock because you can mock with less implementation

Answer (score 2):

We use RhinoMocks and NUnit for our .NET projects. JUnit will be the Java alternative

Answer (score 2):

NMock is far from being best mock framework in .NET world.
It is string based:

```
Expect.Once.On(mockView).GetProperty("FromAccount").Will(Return.Value("1234"));
```

I strongly suggest somethingmore up-to-date like [Rhino.Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx):

```
Expect.Call(mockView.FromAccount).Returns("1234");
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's important to separate the concepts of *testing* and *mocking*.  For **unit-testing** (to drive your tests), **JUnit** (for Java) and **NUnit** (for .NET) are the most popular choices.  The situation around mocking (or isolation) frameworks is more complicated.

**Mocking frameworks** divide into two camps, which I like to call "conventional" and "alternative."

Conventional frameworks rely primarily on design for testability and dependency injection.  Alternative frameworks rely on things like [Profiling API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404386.aspx) or the Java 5 SE instrumentation feature (the java.lang.instrument package) to modify CIL or bytecode at runtime, which makes any dependency mockable.

Examples of such alternative networks are [Typemock Isolator](http://learn.typemock.com/Downloads.php) (for .NET) and [JMockit](https://jmockit.dev.java.net/) (for Java) (Typemock is not free unless you use it in an open-source project.)

As for the **conventinal mocking frameworks for .NET**, the two most popular ones currently are [RhinoMocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) and [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/).  Both rely heavily on C# 3.0 features, particularly the lambda syntax, to allow concise specifications of mock object behaviors and expectations.

Comment: Great answer! Just a small correction: the JMockit project moved to Google Code last october; the current url is http://code.google.com/p/jmockit.

Comment: Rogerio: thank you for the correction! I'm more up-to-date on .NET stuff than on Java.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/) in some Java projects and I like it very much.
There seems to be a [.net port](http://sourceforge.net/projects/easymocknet/) but I haven't used it yet, personally.

Concerning unit tests, I use [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/) 4.x, which has some nice extensions compared to 3.x. I guess [NUnit](http://nunit.org/) provides similar functionality but haven't used it, either.

Answer (score 0):

We use MbUnit and Rhino.Mocks for testing. I really like it.

The reason we use MbUnit is the Reflector.. Perhaps it can be found in NUnit also, but I found it in MbUnit first ;)